# PyGame : How to use "get_rect" function for images in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I started creating a new game with PyGame in Python, I put all my sprite's images in a list, so when I will be moving the sprite with the arrows, it will read the list which has the sprite's images and it will give a reality effect (because we will see the sprite's legs moving).
The problem is that apparently **we can't use `get_rect` for images in a list** | ERROR : `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_rect'`

Here is my code :

```
import os
import pygame
pygame.init()

current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'images')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shoot The Villains")
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'icon.png')))

class Player (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = 25
        self.y = 640
        self.health_Player = 100
        self.reamaning_health_Player = self.health_Player / (20/13)
        self.attackDMG = 10
        self.speed = 7.5
        self.jumpCount = self.speed
        self.countSteps = 0
        self.go_left = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche1-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche2-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche3-4.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche4-4.png'))]
        self.go_right = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit1-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit2-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit3-4.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit4-4.png'))]
        self.rectLeft = self.go_left[0:len(self.go_left)].get_rect ### THIS LINE ###
        self.rectRight = self.go_right[0:len(self.go_right)].get_rect ### THIS LINE ###
```

This is the last 2 lines.
**I didn't put all my code, because I think it's useless.**
It's not my very first time I code in Python, but I'm not a seasoned coder either, so don't be amazed if you see other errors apart from the last two lines.

Thanks for taking the time to review my issue !

Comment: It's `.get_rect()`  you forgot the `()` to make it a function call.

Comment: Yes, I forgot, thank you. But it still doesn't work Error : AttributeError: `'list' object has no attribute 'get_rect'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `self.rectLeft` is the list of rectangles of the images in `self.go_left` then you cannot initialise it this way.

The error raised tells you cannot apply method `get_rect` on a list object.  If you want to apply `get_rect` on the images of your list then you have to do it for each item individually and not on the list itself.

There are several ways to do that.  One is to use a *list comprehension* :

```py
self.rectLeft = [img.get_rect() for img in self.go_left]
```

Comment: Thank you, now the problem is fixed !!